# Joins & Auto Generated Id in Solr 4.9

Tags: solr

I have the following 2 questions:

1) I was going through the Join query parser in **Solr** here https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join. From the above example, what I understand is that it is not possible to join between 2 separate schemas in **Solr**. The only join that is feasible is a self-join. Did I understand it correctly?

2) I was trying to find a way to create auto-generated id's in **Solr**.
I came across this link https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey, what I understand from this link is that there is a way to create the unique id in **Solr**, but what if I have 2 separate fields in my schema that I want to be auto-generated? Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can join across different cores the syntax is something like:

   {!join from=fromId to=toId fromIndex=Core2}query

So if you have two core that looks something like

**PersonCore** - ID, Name

**AddressCore** - ID, Address, PersonID

You can find all people at a specific address by querying the PersonCore like this:

```
{!join from=PersonID to=ID fromIndex=AddressCore}Address:Address1
```

2. You can only have one UniqueKey. It might be possible to auto generate another unique field value though, have a look here:

http://solr.pl/en/2013/07/08/automatically-generate-document-identifiers-solr-4-x/

I've never used this because I always used a unique key from the data being indexed but it might be worth looking into? If you were to add another field name into the updateRequestProcessorChain section descibed in solrconfig.xml would that generate another unique ID? I'm not sure but it's something to try

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have tried  the example in the link but it seems that the autogenerated id will be working for a single field only.